# Getting issue to upload picture in virtualhost server php no error only [tmp_name] => [error] => 6 didn't set upload_tmp_dir in php.ini file

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

issue with me

> Array (
> [image] => Array
> (
> [name] => living-room7.jpg
> [full_path] => living-room7.jpg
> [type] =>
> [tmp_name] =>
> [error] => 6
> [size] => 0
> )
>
> ) File upload failed with error code: 6

and my written code is try all but it give same output

```
if($action === "uploadServiceImage" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST') {
$folder = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'folder');
$targetDirectory = "../assets/product-images/".$folder."/";
$targetFile = $targetDirectory.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)) {

  $status = $usermodel->uploadServiceImage($_FILES['image']['name'],$folder);
  if($status==1) {
     header("location: ../admin/services.php?upload=file upload successfully");
  }
  else {
     echo "file not uploades in database";
  }
}
else {
     echo "File upload failed with error code: " .$_FILES['image']['error'];
}
```

}

I want to upload image from website to server but it can't upload give
Array
(
[image] => Array
(
[name] => living-room7.jpg
[full_path] => living-room7.jpg
[type] =>
[tmp_name] =>
[error] => 6
[size] => 0
)

)
File upload failed with error code: 6

this output